# Windows Forms TextImageRelation Layout Math

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a custom Windows Forms `Label` control with a much needed `TextImageRelation` property, just like `Buttons` have. However, I don't understand how `Buttons` are dividing their internal space between the `Text` and `Image` for the various `TextAlign` and `ImageAlign` combinations. I've spent far too much time playing with the designer trying to reverse engineer the logic, and I just don't get it. Can someone please explain to me how this layout is being calculated?

Comment: There is nothing particularly simple about it and there's no hope of re-using the code since it is all *internal*.  The [LayoutOptions class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonBaseAdapter.cs,4391c93a609401b1) has 30 fields, of course you can't reverse engineer the logic.  You'll have to cut corners.

Comment: How buttons and labels draw their internal areas is different way down in the GDI layer.  The Label is almost text only and the Button has some image capabilities on its surface.   I would investigate using two controls (image and label) or using a button that looks like a label and behaves like a label.

Comment: I managed to figure out the logic behind ImageBeforeText and ImageAboveText, but the other options don't make any sense to me whatsoever. I ended up making up my own layout logic that makes more sense. To me at least.